# Regex match anything between multiple times from git log

Tags: javascript, regex

I want split the git log message into parts, so I can access each commit and its hash and message separated.

This is the git log command:

```sh
git log --pretty=short --abbrev-commit -n 2 HEAD
```

Here an example log:

```
commit bfb9bac
Author: XXXXX XXXXXXXX <xxx.xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx>

    Something awesome happened here

commit a4fad44
Author: XXXXX XXXXXXXX <xxx.xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx>

    Ooh, more awesomeness
    So many lines
```

what I have tried so far:

```regex
([a-f0-9]{7})\n(?:Author.+\n\n)([\s\S]+)(?=\ncommit)
```

here a link to RegExr: https://regexr.com/4d523

at the end it should look like this:

```
const result = commits.match(regex)

result[0][0] // bfb9bac
result[0][1] // Something awesome happened here

result[1][0] // a4fad44
result[1][1] // Ooh, more awesomeness\n    So many lines
```

It would be also okay to do this in two steps; first splitting the commits and then splitting hash and message.

Comment: It is not clear as to what you want to match and what should be your expected output from your given sample data. There is no `sha1` in your data, I guess you meant that alphanumeric string but please be clear and edit your post to add your expected output clearly as to currently you are getting this and expected is this.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi it is a sha1 hash but shortened. Anyway edited it to be more clear.

Comment: the example log is a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the use of `[\s\S]` by matching the whole string using `.*` and repeting a pattern that matches a newline and asserts that the string does not start with commit:

```
^commit ([a-f0-9]{7})\nAuthor.*\n+[ \t]+(.*(?:\n(?!commit).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `commit` Match *commit* followed by a space
- `([a-f0-9]{7})` Capture in group 1 matching 7 times what is listed in the character class
- `\nAuthor.*` Match a newline, then Author and 0+ times any char except a newline
- `\n+[ \t]+` Match 1+ times a newline followed by 1+ spaces or tabs
- `(` Capturing group

  - `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
  - `(?:\n(?!commit).*)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a newline, assert what is on the right is not commit, then match any char 0+ times except a newline
- `)` Close capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN4Fg5/1)

```js
const regex = /^commit ([a-f0-9]{7})\nAuthor.*\n+[ \t]+(.*(?:\n(?!commit).*)*)/gm;
const str = `commit bfb9bac
Author: XXXXX XXXXXXXX <xxx.xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx>

    Something awesome happened here

commit a4fad44
Author: XXXXX XXXXXXXX <xxx.xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx>

    Ooh, more awesomeness
    So many lines
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log("hash: " + m[1]);
  console.log("message: " + m[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex to match each of the commit log and capture sha1 in group1 and message in group2,

```
^commit\s+(\S+)\n^Author:[\w\W]+?^\s+((?:(?!commit)[\w\W])+)
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `^commit` - Starts matching `commit` at the beginning of line
- `\s+(\S+)\n` - Matches one or more whitespace followed by sha1 value which gets captured in group1 using `(\S+)` followed by a newline `\n`
- `^Author:[\w\W]+?` - Again starts matching `Author` from start of line followed by colon followed by any character one or more times as less as possible
- `^\s+` - This matches one or more whitespace from the beginning of line and this is the point from which message will start getting captured by next regex part
- `((?:(?!commit)[\w\W])+)` - This expression (aka **[tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html)**) captures any character including newlines using `[\w\W]` but stops capturing if it sees `commit` and places the whole match in group2

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dOoUfk/1)**

Here is a JS code demo,

```js
str = `commit bfb9bac
Author: XXXXX XXXXXXXX <xxx.xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx>

    Something awesome happened here

commit a4fad44
Author: XXXXX XXXXXXXX <xxx.xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx>

    Ooh, more awesomeness
    So many lines`;

reg = new RegExp(/^commit\s+(\S+)\n^Author:[\w\W]+?^\s+((?:(?!commit)[\w\W])+)/mg);
while(null != (m=reg.exec(str))) {
   console.log("SHA1: " + m[1] + ", Message: " + m[2]);
}
```